# Android Rating Bar with "No Rating" Option

Tags: android, ratingbar

Is it possible to have an android Rating bar, having an different drawable or view as the first "star" i.e.?

So I could interpret rating = 0 as "no value"  and rating= 1 as "Very Bad"?

MY current solution is using a switchCompat:
[image]

Comment: Probably, but why not 0?

Comment: Because Rating = 0 means bad. Rating = null means not rated or no rating given.
This is important for my application.

Comment: OK. You could programmatically change the drawable on user tap. Like: I tap 0, you show nothing; I tap 1, you show 1 sad face; I tap 2,3,4,5, you show 2,3,4,5 happy smiles. Is that OK?

Comment: wouldn't all icons change at once ?

Comment: Yes, you can't have one sad and one happy icon at the same time, but you can dynamically change *all* stars when the rating has a particular value. You can have `X----` or `OOO--` , but never `XOO--` .

Comment: Maybe someone knows a way how to do it. Or  a library for it.

Answer (score 0):

may be you are looking for this rating bar library

[Custom XML Shape](https://github.com/tigerpenguin/SimpleRatingBar)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there is no "no rating" option neighter there is the possiblility to set individual caracters.